# Cumulative product with r

Tags: r

I want to do something usual in excel but I don't know how to do it with R:

```
10        * 1.01 = 10.1 
(10+10.1) * 1.02 = 20.502
(10+20.5) * 1.03 = ...
```

It is like cumprod but * by an external vector.

Edit:

I have two vectors one can be: c(50, 52, 54, 55) and the other one c(1.01, 1.02, 1.03, 1.04) and I want to do:

```
50 * 1.01 = 50.5
(50.5 + 52) * 1.02 = 104.55
...
```

I want to get a vector at each step without "for".

Thanks

Comment: It's not very clear what are you trying to do. Can you provide some example vectors? Also, what function you use for that in Excel?

Comment: Do you want your output to be a vector that shows the result at each step or just the final number?

Comment: does this go to the infinity?

Comment: I added an example, Thanks!

Comment: How on earth `50 * 0.01 = 50.5`? Is that some new mathematics there?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try

```
x <- 1 + 1:100/100 
f <- function(i) 10*sum(cumprod(x[i:1]))
# first 10 elements
sapply(1:10, f)
# [1]  10.10000  20.50200  31.41706  43.07374  55.72743  69.67108  85.24805
# [8] 102.86789 123.02601 146.32861
```

Answer for edited question: just an adaptation of above.

```
a <- c(50, 52, 54, 55)
b <- c(1.01, 1.02, 1.03, 1.04)
f1 <- function(i)sum((a[i:1])*cumprod(b[i:1]))
sapply(1:4, f1)
#[1]  50.5000 104.5500 163.3065 227.0388
```

Comment: What do you mean by *Vectorize* in this context?

Comment: I used Vectorize as a euphemism for "don't use loops". Is it not vectorized?

Comment: `sapply` is a loop written in R as opposed to a *Vectorized* loop which is written in C/C++ (such as `rowSums` for example) so not sure what you mean by that. Though I don't critique your approach, just wanted to understand what you meant. R loops are perfectly fine too, they just don't go under the *Vectorized* category.

Comment: I see your point. Most vectorized operations in R are just a plain loops in other languages, so the use of vectorize technically is wrong, and ambiguous at best. Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: No. The vectorized terminology should be avoided only when you are running a loop that *is written in R* (such as `for`, `while`, `sapply` and all the rest of the `*apply` family, etc.). All the rest of the loops (C/C++/Fortran) are called vectorized. But this terminology is not *that* important, you can say what you want basically :)

Comment: Ah, by vectorize I was referring to `sum` and `cumprod`, not `sapply`.

Answer (score 1):

What about using the following loop?

```
v <- rep(NA, 3)
for(i in 1:length(v)){
    v[i] <- (max(v[i-1], 0) + 10)*(1 + i/100)
}
v
[1] 10.10000 20.50200 31.41706
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just want the final product you could create a function:

```
## Create equal length vectors
x <- rep(10, 10)
y <- seq(1.01, 1.1, .01)

## Create function
accumProd <- function(x, y){
  z = 0
  for (i in 1:length(x)){
    z <- (x[i]+z) * y[i]
  }
  z
}

accumProd(x,y)
[1] 146.3286
```

Comment: Thanks, but I want it at each step.